# ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found with 4 Maximum Worker Process

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have two reports, return.aspx, and salary.aspx. The report viewer appears to display the reports randomly, while at other times, I encounter the error message: "ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found." I observed that the Maximum Worker Process was initially set to 4, and after adjusting it to 1, the issue resolved.

Hearder of my report code below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="return.aspx.cs" Inherits="" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

Is there a possible way to run both reports with the Maximum Worker Process set to 4?